# Entity Framework: Object can't be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, service, repository

I've run into a problem, I know why it's a problem, but don't know the right way to fix it.

So my controller sends a Product to my Service class, along with 2 strings defining the category of the object.

Here's the service class.

```
public Product AddProduct(Product p, string cat, string subcat)
{
    var category = _categoryService.GetCategoryByName(cat, subcat);
    p.Categories.Add(category);
    return _productRepository.CreateProduct(p);
}
```

The first line get's an exisiting category( CategroyService->CategoryRepository->DbContext), so here I use an instance of My context.

Then I add that Category to my list of categories of the product. And finally I give to the repository and that persists it to my Database ( trough EF ofcourse ).

Then I get the error

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

I think it's because I first ask for a category, and then try to add a product. The change tracker then needs to hold track of 2 contexts and it gets confused. The thing is I don't get why the first context from the category doesn't get disposed when I have my category.

What should I do?

EDIT:

The _categoryService uses another repository than ProductRepository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using more instances of DbContext in one request (unit of work) as you have already mentioned.

When you develop a web application the best way is to work with a different instance of DbContext for every web request, but exaclty 1 instance for 1 request and call SaveChanges only 1 time when you made all the changes you need.

This is very easy to do if you use an IoC framework, like Unity and let your DbContext injected in your Repositories.

In this case you should use the following settings (if you use Unity):

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, YourDbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), ...);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd already changes some responsibilities, and indeed only called the context once and saved once